# Does GWT 1.7 have support for Class.getSimpleName()?

Tags: gwt

Does GWT 1.7 have support for `Class.getSimpleName()`?

I am currently using 1.6, and it does not support this method.

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3404 says its been fixed but not released, but perhaps the status hasn't been updated for a while.

I could easily replicate it myself by manipulating `Class.getName()`, but if GWT 1.7 supports this method, then I will upgrade to it.

Comment: [GWT 2.0](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.0/ReleaseNotes_2_0#BugFixes) seems to have added support for ´Class.getSimpleName()´.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the release notes](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_6_0_RC1) they added it in GWT 2.6.0 RC1. Scroll down to **JDK Emulation**

Answer (score 11):

Fortunately it's easy enough to work around. `this.getClass().getName().substring(this.getClass().getName().lastIndexOf(".")+1);`

Comment: Oops didn't mean to include the ternary op, but you get the picture.

Answer (score 3):

Nope.

```
[ERROR] Line 23: The method getSimpleName() is undefined for the type Class<capture#1-of ? extends SimpleTest>
```