# How to get simple classname from class with interface reference?

Tags: java, gwt

If a class implements an interface, how can I get the name of the class implementation, without the fully qualified package?

```
interface HasText;
class Base extends HasText;

List<HasText> texts;

for (HasText text : texts) {
     //Error: The method getSimpleName() is undefined for the type Class<capture#1-of ? extends HasText>
     Sysout(text.getClass().getSimpleName());

     //prints: my.package.to.Base
     Sysout(text.getClass().getName());
}
```

How to get only 'Base' as output without package declaration?

Comment: [`Class.getSimpleName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName()) should work on all `Class` objects, no matter if it comes from an "interface type" or not.

Comment: Yep, `text.getClass().getSimpleName()` should compile fine.

Comment: The problem is likely somewhere else in your code. It will be helpful to get some more context.

Comment: are you compiling with the correct java version?

Comment: I'm using GWT, to probably there's some error in the framework itself...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does GWT 1.7 have support for Class.getSimpleName()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132692/does-gwt-1-7-have-support-for-class-getsimplename)

Comment: @membersound: if you're using GWT, then please mention that in your question in the future (and tag accordingly), because it **does** make quite a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using GWT SDK of >2.4 i.e `2.5.x`   `Class.getSimpleName()`  now [supports](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/release-notes).

Comment: Actually, the [relevant commit](https://gwt-review.googlesource.com/#/c/2220/) is still under review, so nothing has landed yet (unfortunately).

Comment: @AndreaBoscolo Thanks for the update Andrea.When can we expect that?

Comment: I'm not a gwt committer, so I can't say, but the patch set seems pretty straightforward. I guess it's just a matter of commit relevance. In the meantime it should be possible to apply that patch to a local gwt git repol, or super-source that `user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/lang/Class.java`.

Answer (score 3):

So as this should work in general, I only came up with the following workaround:

```
String name = text.getClass().getName();
name = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
```

Comment if I might be doing better...